# Grouping result in show in columnar format in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck somewhere to count the results and converting them into columns. I tried with pivoting, but could not do it. Can anybody please help on the following:

```
E   W   A
101 P   1
102 P   3
101 Q   4
102 Q   4
103 P   3
103 Q   1
104 P   5
104 Q   1
105 P   3
105 Q   2
```

And the output as follows:

```
W   1   2   3   4   5
P   1   0   3   0   1
Q   2   1   0   2   0
```

The logic is I just wanted to count the no of time `1,2,3,4,5` appeared for each `W`. For example, `W=P and A=3` appeared thrice, but `W=P and A=1` appeared only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmer's answer and I prefer to use `CASE WHEN` like this:

```
SELECT W, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `1`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `2`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `3`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `4`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `5`
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY W
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT W, 
    SUM(A = 1) AS `1`, 
    SUM(A = 2) AS `2`, 
    SUM(A = 3) AS `3`, 
    SUM(A = 4) AS `4`,
    SUM(A = 5) AS `5`
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY W
```